# how to set width to self.minimun_width of the boxlayout widget into py file not kv file

Tags: python, kivy

i need to set the width for boxlayout widget to minimun_width to use it into scrollview what is the wrong in this code ?

```
BoxLayout(size_hint_x=None , width=self.minimum_width)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need binding. Try it like,

```py
box = BoxLayout(size_hint_x=None)
box.bind(minimum_width=box.setter("width"))
```

This (binding) will automatically set (by using default callback [`setter`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.event.html?highlight=setter#kivy.event.EventDispatcher.setter)) the `width` of the `box` to its `minimum_width` whenever a widget of fixed width is added to it.